# How to add additional column in select when using *?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have

```
select * from table where id = 3;
```

but I would like to also make a transformation on one column, so something like this:

```
select replace(aaa, 'a', 'b'), * from table where id = 3;
```

but this does not work. Anybody knows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select replace(aaa, 'a', 'b'), t.* from table t where id = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

the reason is because `asterisk` `*` came after the replace manipulation, try interchanging it and it will work fine,

```
select  *, 
        replace(aaa, 'a', 'b')  
from    `table` 
where   id = 3;
```